# posterior predictive accuracy: the role of log and the point - predictive density value

Tags: self-study, bayesian, model

1. posterior - predictive checks: a predictive model built based on a set of
   empirical observations $x$ so that $x$ may be compared against a set of prediction $\tilde{x} \sim p(\tilde{x} | x)$

Then, for posterior - predictive accuracy: a predictive model: the set of predictions $\tilde{x} \sim p(\tilde{x} | x)$ to be compared against a set of out - of - samples $\tilde{\tilde{x}}$.

is this correct?

2. I read somewhere that the posterior - predictive accuracy can be summarised by the log of the posterior - predictive density value.

The posterior - predictive density value is defined as $P_{p}(.) = \int d\theta p(. | \theta) p(\theta | x)$ where $p(. | \theta)$ is the point - predictive density value.

So, the posterior - predictive accuracy is $l_{p} = log\left[ P_{p}(.)\right]$.

Does anyone know of an explicit form to the point - predictive density value $P(. | \theta)$? What role does the point -predictive density value $p(. | \theta)$ play in the posterior - predictive density value $P_{p}(.)$?
What would $P_{p}(.)$ tell me?
Are there good examples to $P(. | \theta)$? Why is the significance of the logarithm operator?